# Get Array from Moxtra output

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value of 'download_url' from this pre tag that's generated from Moxtra, using jQuery? And also assign it to a variable.

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
  {"data":{"recordings":
  [{"content_type":"video/mp4","content_length":67154,"download_url":"https://www.moxtra.com/board/BMNXjACUHm2CrYQy8ggK7bI/19","created_time":1422748565448}],"count":1},"code":"RESPONSE_SUCCESS"}
</pre>
```

For code, just assume the url that this array is on is www.someurl.com

Answer (score 1):

```
var download_url = JSON.parse($pre.text()).data.recordings[0].download_url;
```

`$pre` is a jQuery object for your `<pre>` element. How you obtain that object depends on where is that element stored (right in the page's DOM, or in a DocumentFragment, or in whatever).

However, this is quite an unwieldy way, are you sure there isn't an API for Moxtra that just gives you JSON data so you don't have to search for it inside a  element? Or maybe API did give you JSON and you mistakingly inserted it into an HTML element?

Comment: Ok, but how do I get at the pre if it's on another page at url:  www.someurl.com ?  And no, there's no API to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, so it is on another domain even. Accessing other domains with javascript on your page is impossible due to security limitations, however it sometimes can be done, but in a manner not related to your question, for example, with JSONP (again, that probably won't be useful for your case).

Comment: I know Script and JSONP requests are not subject to cross-domain restrictions using ajax.  Can you help me using either of those, as Moxtra really has given no other alternatives.

Comment: Those only work if the other end (that website) actually has an intention for you to use their cross-domain API. Maybe for your task you could use something other than javascript in browser?

Comment: I would assume Moxtra will allow cross-domain using their API.  If that's so, can you suggest a solution.  I really need to use javascript/jQuery or php.

Comment: Have you searched for an answer here? https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-js-sdk/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69975/discussion-between-parti-and-suseika).

Answer (score 1):

Had to use Query YQL plugin, due to the limitations of cross-domain.  Finally got the right object value using queryYQL method.